# Is there a mistake in my calculations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

I am trying solve the differential equation $y''+3y'+2y=u(t-1)-u(t-2), y(0)=y'(0)=0$, by calculating the convolution of $f(t)=1$ and $g(t)=e^{-t}-e^{-2t}$. The problem is that I get two different answers for $(f \ast g)$ and $(g \ast f)$. Does anyone see if the mistake is in my reasoning or in my calculations?

for $1<t<2$:
$\int_0^t f(t-\tau)g(\tau) = \int_1^t [e^{-\tau}-e^{-2\tau}]d\tau = \frac{1}{2}e^{-2t}-e^{-t}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2}+e^{-1}$,

$\int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau) = \int_1^t [e^{-(t-\tau)}-e^{-2(t-\tau)}]d\tau = \frac{1}{2}e^{-2(t-1)}-e^{-(t-1)}+\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Review the inferior limit of integration, at the begining you set as $0$ and in the next step it seems you are taking it as $1$.

Comment: But isn't that because the right hand side of the differential equation is 0 for t < 1? I took this example from "Advanced Engineering Mathematics", (Kreyszig, 9th ed., p.252). He splits the integral into two cases, one for t > 2 and another for 1 < t < 2. In the 1 < t < 2 case he integrates from 1 to t. However, he doesn't explain why.

Comment: The integration limits have to do with the bound of $t$. Since $t > 1$ there is no reason to integrate from $t = 0$. However, more context is needed, particularly how you solved this equation. Did you take the Laplace transform and back?

Comment: Yes, and this problem is from an example, so both f(t) and g(t) are provided. But what I don't understand is why (f * g) =/= (g * f) ? Are they not supposed to be, or is my integration wrong?